# Convert Php array in javascript array

Tags: php, javascript

I have php array like this

```
[0]->imgae_name=1
 image_url=a

[1]->imgae_name=2
 image_url=b
```

i want to convert this array in javascript array
how can i do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the PHP array to JSON using `json_encode`, then echo the json string into the Javascript in your page and use Javascript `JSONObject` to convert it into a JS array

Comment: I think eval is more then enough in javascript :D

Comment: @JeffLee not to split hairs, but doesn't eval() return an Object not an Array?  I know the difference is little, but just going with the OP's question here. ;)

Comment: I see :D hahahaa  I like json more the array :D

Answer (score 1):

```
json_encode($your_array);
```

is the right way to do this. It converts your php array to this string:

```
[{imgae_name:1,image_url:"a"},{imgae_name:2,image_url:"b"}]
```

Then you only have to assign it to a variable in a script tag.

Answer (score 0):

In php

```
<?
$array = array("A" => "1", "B" => "2");
echo json_encode($array);
?>
```

In Javascript

```
var mObject = eval("(" + phpecho + ")");
```

Then you can access the value :

```
 mObject.A // 1
```